# Maximum of parametric equation y(t) with respect to x(t), find ArgMax x(t)

Tags: parametric-functions, maximum

```
x0=0
x1 =d
x2 = 2d
x3= 3d
x[t_] = (1-t)^3*x0+3*t*(1-t)^2*x1+3*t^2*(1-t)*x2+t^3*x3
y0=S/(x^2)
y1=S/((x-d)^2)
y2=S/((2d-x)^2)
y3=S/((3d-x)^2)
y[t_] = (1-t)^3*y0+3*t*(1-t)^2*y1+3*t^2*(1-t)*y2+t^3*y3
```

The above code explains the parametric functions `x[t]`, `y[t]`. I need to find the max value of `y[t]` with respect to `x[t]`. I tried it in this way,

```
t /. Solve[{D[y[t], t]==0}, t] but cloud timed out.
```

but the t expression if too large and x[t] does not give a proper expression. I want `x[t]` expression at which `y[t]` is maximized.

Answer (score 1):

Solve gives two solutions:

```
solt=Solve[D[y[t], t]/D[x[t], t] == 0, t] 
(*{{t -> -((-18 d^5 + 66 d^4 x - 65 d^3 x^2 + 24 d^2 x^3 - 3 d x^4 + 
    Sqrt[-d^2 x^2 (-3 d + x)^2 (5 d^4 - 27 d^3 x + 36 d^2 x^2 - 
       18 d x^3 + 3 x^4)])/(6 d^2 (3 d^3 - 11 d^2 x + 9 d x^2 - 
      2 x^3)))}, {t -> (18 d^5 - 66 d^4 x + 65 d^3 x^2 - 
  24 d^2 x^3 + 3 d x^4 + 
  Sqrt[-d^2 x^2 (-3 d + x)^2 (5 d^4 - 27 d^3 x + 36 d^2 x^2 - 
     18 d x^3 + 3 x^4)])/(6 d^2 (3 d^3 - 11 d^2 x + 9 d x^2 - 
    2 x^3))}}*)
```

which can be substituted to get x[t]

```
 Simplify[ {x[t], y[t]} /. solt]
```